# How to use column value as column name or calculation symbol on Select-List

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to convert query working on SQLITe to ORACLE of version 18C now.
But there is problem.

What I want is "Use column (string)value as column name or calculation symbol on Select-List".
With SQLITE example)
table with column

- `q1 number`
- `q2 number`
- `calc varchar

and value of a sample record for each column is

```
0.1, 0.2, q1+q2
```

then when I used query like below

```
select q1, q2, (calc) * 1 from table;
```

the result set is

```
0.1, 0.2, 0.3
```

In SQLITE, String value of column can use as column name and calculation symbol.

I tried to find similar way with oracle, but failed.
Is there any possible method without using PL/SQL or dynamic query?

Comment: "*without using PL/SQL or dynamic query*" - no

Comment: Thank you for your edit. it was my first poor question.Finally just decide to use pl/sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in SQL like the below using XMLquery.**[The DB fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=101fc92f06ba86ad87e3f86e69912348)**

**Update 1**:-for modulo operation of q1 by q2 use `q1 mod q2`.
    For q1 to the power q2 use `math:pow(q1,q2)`.For more Xquery function reference is available [here](https://www.altova.com/xpath-xquery-reference)

```
  with calc1 as (select q1,q2,replace(replace(calc,'q1',q1),'q2',q2) calc from tt)
  select q1,q2, xmlquery(replace( calc, '/', ' div ' ) 
                        returning content ) .getNumberVal() calc from calc1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is

```
select q1, q2,
       q1 + q2 as result
from some_table;
```

Or, create a function (if you insist) and use it afterwards:

```
SQL> create or replace function calc (par_1 in number, par_2 in number)
  2  return number
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return par_1 + par_2;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> with test (q1, q2) as
  2    (select 1, 8 from dual union all
  3     select -4, 24 from dual
  4    )
  5  select q1, q2, calc(q1, q2) result
  6  from test;

        Q1         Q2     RESULT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          8          9
        -4         24         20

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
But it is somewhat different what I want.
In Calc column, there are many values like 'q1/q2', 'q1*2+q2', 'q1*q2' etc.
And I simplified question using three columns... but actually there are q1~q9 number type columns and Calc column. 
And I tried to express with onequery without hardcoding all case of calc column and using function, pl/sql.
Could you help me further?

Comment: I don't know SQLITE and don't know what CALC columns do. But, from what you described, I don't think that something like that exists - you'd have to write your own function and do all those calculations.